# Is it ok to derive initialization vector from password (as with key), given the salt will be random?

Tags: c#, java, encryption, cryptography

Cryptography gurus please help.

I've learned that encryption key with symmetric algorithms (e.g. AES) should be derived from password via the PBKDF2 function, using the random salt in each encryption. I've also learned that IV should not be hard-coded, or directly bound to (derived from) password string or encryption key. Until now I was generating **both** key derivation salt **and** IV randomly, 16 bytes each for my AES-256 encryption, and storing them along with encrypted payload.

Now I'm thinking random-generation of IV is redundant, if I use random salt, as I can derive both key and IV from password string with that salt. Or maybe I shouldn't?

So my question is ultimately this:

Can I derive initialization vector from password (as I do with key), or should I generate random IV each time, given the fact that I use random salt in each encryption?

So can I use the below C# code?

```
// Derive key and initialization vector from password:

// ---> NOTE: _salt is random 16 bytes in each encryption.

byte[] key, iv;

using (Rfc2898DeriveBytes derivedBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, _salt, _iterations))
{
    key = derivedBytes.GetBytes(32);
    iv = derivedBytes.GetBytes(16);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can use it that way, as long as you never ever use the same salt for the same password (even in time) to calculate the key and IV. The IV only has to be unique when you encrypt with the same key, and you would calculate a new key each time. In principle you could even use an all zero IV, as the key is never repeated, but you are better off using a derived one.

Note that if one of your colleagues decides that `PasswordDeriveBytes` - the broken implementation of PBKDF1 from Microsoft - would be better suited for the task, then you may very well be vulnerable to all kinds of attacks. This is just an example what can go wrong if your security margins are tight...

Fully random IV's should certainly be preferred.

Comment: Can you explain what `PasswordDeriveBytes` would break? And why is it a broken implementation?

Comment: @CodesInChaos: It actually repeats output when you call `getBytes()` multiple times. It's a badly written, not documented extension by Microsoft on PBKDF1. PBKDF1 only outputs a single digest size if implemented by spec.. It generates different outputs when `getBytes` is called with 48 bytes, or first 32 then 16 bytes. The devs of Mono even have this functionality as no-fix. There is quite some (hard to find) info on the internet about this, mostly on the Mono mailing list if I'm not mistaken. Basically, it is FUBAR.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean " using the random salt in each encryption"? It is best to derive the salt and IV randomly, such as the output from a cryptography standard random number generator and store it with the derived bytes. Generate a new IV and salt for each password.

Why from a cryptography standard RNG? Deriving from the password means any weakness in the derive bytes function is reflected in both the bytes and the IV. It is not difficult in modern programming languages to generate it from a RNG and using a RNG ensures the IV for new passwords encrypted is not predictable. There are probably better reasons but I am drawing a blank.

Comment: Yes I'm using the `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` secure random generator to generate the 16-byte salt. The question is: should I also generate IV randomly, or is it ok to derive it from password string using that same salt, which is used for key derivation?

Comment: I would generate the IV randomly, too. It means it must be stored rather than derived but this is the case for most symmetric encryption use. The other reasons in the second paragraph also apply.

Answer (score 0):

The more links there are between different parts of any crypto system then the easier it will be for any attacker to use those links as a back door from one part of the system to another.  Remember that the IV is sent in the clear while the key **must** be kept secret, so any sort of link between them is a huge risk to take.

Use `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` to generate your key and use a good crypto RNG to generate the IV.  Remember that the attacker will see the IV so there is no need to go through the full RFC 2898 process.  Use the standard crypto RNG for the IV that will probably be faster than the RFC 2898 process because it does not have the iterations.

Comment: Well, you suppose generating IV randomly would be good, which it obviously is. But I asked - is it mandatory? If you say it is, I'd like to hear arguments. In my schema IV won't be derived from key, it will be derived from password, and with randomized salt at that. I'd like to hear what theoretical threats, if any, are associated with that.

Comment: @TX_: In your schema, the IV is generated immediately after the key.  That tells the attacker that after generating your key, the RFC2898 engine was in a state such that the next 16 bytes generated were your IV.  That gives the attacker altogether too much information about the RFC2898 state vector at the end of the key generation process.  Great swathes of possible state vectors can immediately be eliminated because they don't result in the right IV.  That gives away altogether too much information about possible keys.

Comment: While your theory is interesting, I don't think it is applicable here, because: It assumes that based on returned bytes of second `GetBytes` call, you can make some educated guess about the set of possible values for the bytes returned by previous `GetBytes` call. But `GetBytes` most probably involves some one-way hashing routines that make it impossible to make predictions about previously generated sequence, based on current sequence. Like if you hash MD5 string again with MD5, you can't guess what could the previous MD5 be based on current MD5.

Comment: PBKDF2 (which is implemented by `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, another idiotic name used by Microsoft) can be used to generated a "key" up to 2^32 - 1 bytes. If any part of that key would be predictable by using another part of the key then the PBKDF2 function would obviously not be correct. PBKDF1, which is also described in the 
RFC can only be used up to the output size of the hash function.

Comment: @owlstead Using PBKDF2 to generate longer outputs is often a bad idea. In particular if part of the output is enough to reject a wrong password.

Answer (score 0):

The most important part of semantic security for the initialization vector when using AES-CBC is that it should not be predictable.

With your suggested implementation a given key will always have the same initialization vector, but you wouldn't be using the same keys because of your 128 bit salt. Seems pretty unpredictable, that said, it's not a best practice, and generally when you do something clever to save 16 bytes of space your are losing some security of some sort or opening yourself up to some unknown attack vector.

I think you should use RNG and take the space 16 byte hit, being conservative is the name of the game when dealing with encryption. There are other things such as authenticated encryption that you should probably look into as well, I have an [example implementation on codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/14892/review-of-simplified-secure-encryption-of-a-string).

Ultimately there are other things that are important that provide additional overhead beyond the iv for security such as authenticated encryption, versioning, and keyrotation, and there really haven't been any high level encryption frameworks for C#. I've been working a C# implemenation of Google's [Keyczar](http://code.google.com/p/keyczar/) framework. You can follow it, if you like, on github [Keyczar-dotnet](https://github.com/jbtule/keyczar-dotnet/tree/master/dotnet). It's pretty much feature complete, and has 90% test coverage, but conservatively, I wouldn't recommend using it until it gets officially accepted as part of the project, and then will likely have a larger group of eyes on it in the future.